# Neo4j to OrientDB: import database graphml is not importing the properties of nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, graphml

I followed the [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Import-from-Neo4j-into-OrientDB.html) to migrate the data from Neo4j to OrientDB

out.graphml file has the label,type and property information. Snippet from the file below.

```
<node id="n259" labels=":FacebookUser:_FacebookUser"><data key="labels">:FacebookUser:_FacebookUser</data><data key="__type__">com.czen.social.model.FacebookUser</data><data key="firstName">Test</data><data key="lastName">Name</data><data key="id">1000085</data></node>

<edge id="e1172175" source="n402940" target="n5457" label="KNOWS"><data key="label">KNOWS</data><data key="__type__">com.czen.social.model.Relationship</data><data key="hired">true</data><data key="hiredTlm">Tue Apr 21 05:16:36 EDT 2015</data><data key="weight">35</data></edge>
```

After getting the graphml, I tried importing it to OrientDB

```
    orientdb {db=test}> IMPORT DATABASE /tmp/out.graphml
    Importing GRAPHML database from DATABASE /tmp/out.graphml...
    Transaction 14 has been committed in 0ms

    orientdb {db=test}> classes
    CLASSES
    ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
     NAME                                         | SUPERCLASS                         | CLUSTERS   | RECORDS        |
    ----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
     E                                            |                                    | 10         |              0 |
     FacebookUser                                 | V                                  | 11         |           2190 |
     KNOWS                                        | E                                  | 14         |            171 |
```

We get to see the classname for FacebookUser but when we look at its info it doesn't list any property.

```
    orientdb {db=test}> info class FacebookUser

    Class................: FacebookUser
    Super class..........: V
    Default cluster......: facebookuser (id=11)
    Supported cluster ids: [11]
    Cluster selection....: round-robin
```

Is there anything that I am missing while importing it to OrientDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new 2.1 snapshot from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-community/ this issue was resolved. I had to replace field id with uid as otherwise it was getting ignored wasn't shown in the class info.
Thanks Luca for providing the snapshot with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see any properties in the schema, this means you're working in schema-less mode, but the graph could be imported correctly. Try executing this:

```
select * from V
```

and:

```
select * from E
```

Can you see attributes?

Comment: This is what I get when a ran this. Don't see any attributes.

orientdb {db=test}> select * from V

----+-----+------+------------------+--------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|out_KNOWS         |in_KNOWS
----+-----+------+------------------+--------
0   |#9:0 |V     |null              |null
1   |#9:1 |V     |null              |null
2   |#9:2 |V     |null              |null 

How do I change it to schema mode?

Comment: how you resolve this issue ?, i am facing the same issue . can you please help